# What works I can do myself in home electrics?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I googled a bit and searched some topics on this forum about what works I can carry out myself and which should be notified to building regulations or certified by a registered competent person. Based on the details provided in Building Regulations 2010 Part P

I should get an electrician to do the works and certify in the following:

- new kitchen lights
- new circuit in the utility room
- new lights and circuit in the bathroom

But I can do myself the following:

- installing downlights in non-wet rooms
- replace sockets and switches

Is this correct?

Edit: Location England.

Comment: I have uncanny powers of geolocating people but I'm not sure in your case.  Can you [edit] your question to state a country or regulatory zone? (e.g. Wales, California, Germany etc.)

Comment: What is your location in the world county, state, even city makes a difference in some cases. When we discuss home wiring it is referred to as electrical. Electronics is usually solid state control of a device that uses electricity.

Comment: Where you are (and what local rules apply where you are) determines **all,** here. In my location, I can do any electrical work on my own house, or farm if I had a farm, but after that most things require a licensed electrician (*i.e.* work on an apartment, even if I own it, work on a commercial/business location other than a farm I own, etc...) - I do have to follow the same codes as any other worker, regardless.

Comment: Edited, country England.